# unable to Set up Gravatar on my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to add Gravatar to my app

but get "could not find generator gravtastic" on the command line

1. added gem 'gravtastic'
2. ran bundle install

Using warden (1.2.3) 
Using devise (3.1.2) 
Using foreigner (1.6.1) 
Installing gravtastic (3.2.6) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using jbuilder (1.0.2) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using subexec (0.2.3)

- restarted server

  1. rails g gravtastic:install

Could not find generator gravtastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to run a generator?

I think you just have to do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Gravtastic
  gravtastic
end
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/chrislloyd/gravtastic) doesn't mention the gravtastic generator.